# How to compare arrays and get matching data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I have an array `$data`, that looks something like this:

```php
[
  1 => "1234,10-12-2022",
  2 => "1356,01-02-2021",
  3 => "1677,03-05-2020",
];
```

Then, I have another array `$search` that looks like this: `['1234','1677']`

I can get results of any of those items in $data by date,but once I have a match, i need to check if there is a match from another array, and get that date[1] and value[0] as output. Also it is possible that in match all 3 values[0] are present.

How I can find most recent matches of it?

This is what I have tried:

```
    `$f = array_values(array_intersect(array_map(
            function($item){ 
                return explode(',', $item)[0];  
            }, 
        $c), $p));
var_dump($f);//finds match 

if($f){
    //pass this to find date-time but I need most recent one for //every value
        $c = get_comment_meta($user_id,'value');
        $new_to_old = array_reverse($c);
        $newArr = array();
    foreach ( $new_to_old as $x ) {
        $all_course_meta = explode(",", $x);
        array_push ( $newArr, $all_course_meta[0] );
    }
    $uniqueArr = array_unique($newArr);
        $result = array_intersect($uniqueArr, $f);}
var_dump($result);//doeas not returns anything here.`
```

I have tried various loops and array intersect, diff and etc, but without success.

Comment: Why does your first array concatenate two separate values into a string? Normalize it to make it easily comparable, e.g. `$data = array_map(fn($str) => explode(','))`, and get the four-digit item separated. Also, do post the code for your most sensible effort to solve this, and we can take it from there. Start by getting _any_ matches. Then worry about the most recent ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question here, but if you want to compare the first part of the values in the $data with the values in the $search then I think it's will be like this

```
$a = ['1234,10-12-2022', '1356,01-02-2021', '1677,03-05-2020'];
$b = ['1234', '1677'];

array_values(array_intersect(array_map(function($item){ return explode(',', $item)[0];  }, $a), $b));
```

the output should be

```
=> [
     "1234",
     "1677",
   ]
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: Hi, yes it is helpful to normalize it but to get the most recent from $a is not.